# Why few places are not returned with coordinates while using geocode?

Tags: geopandas, geocode

I have used another code snippet from below which returns (0,0).In this it returns 'NoneType' object is not iterable . I am not getting coordinates for Amasebailu and Hiriyadka places in udupi district

```
!pip install geocoder
!pip install geopandas
import geocoder
from geopandas.tools import geocode
info = geocode('Amasebailu',provider="nominatim")
info
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `Amasebailu` is not present in OSM database, which Nominatim uses for geocoding. You can check directly on https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Amasebailu. So you will have to use some alternative name (if that exist) or geocode these places manually.